# Get XML from a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I've a stored procedure that creates an XML with the information contained in a certain table and returns it as a varchar. The xml variable is declared at the beginning of the sql code and returned at the end with a SELECT statement.

Now, if I try to execute the stored procedure in this way

```
 DECLARE @v_XML VARCHAR(MAX)
 exec @v_XML = dbo.proc_myStoredProcedure '1234'
 select @v_XML as ResultMyStoredProcedure
```

on the screen I see the XML as I want printed because of the `SELECT` statement, but the variable `@v_XML` is 0.

Could anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: If the stored procedure returns `XML` - why is your `@v_XML` defined as a  `varchar(max)` ??

Comment: I do not know what your stored procedure is doing, but - in most cases! - SPs are used in a wrong way... This points to a scalar function returning XML... You would make your life much easier...

Comment: Is this question solved? Do you need further help? Please allow me one hint: It would be very kind of you to tick the acceptance check below the best answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you crossed the 15 points border yourself you are - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is this: a stored procedure only ever returns an `Int` value as its return value - typically to indicate success/failure of an operation, or to report back the number of rows affected by an insert, delete, update statement.

It **cannot** ever return a string or a `XML` directly.

You need to either use **output parameters** on the stored procedure, or you need to do a `SELECT` at the end of the procedure - but that result set is not available as return code, you need to grab it like this:

```
-- define the return code
DECLARE @RC INT

-- define the table variable to hold the result set
DECLARE @YourOutput TABLE (XmlData XML)

-- you need to take the result set from the stored procedure
-- and store it into a table variable (or a "real" table, if you wish)
INSERT INTO @YourOutput(XmlData)
    EXECUTE @RC = dbo.proc_myStoredProcedure '1234'

-- return code will be most likely 0
SELECT @RC

-- this table variable now contains your result set output from the stored procedure
SELECT * FROM @YourOutput
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in a comment before I'm pretty sure, that you should use a scalar function rather than a stored procedure. Check this to understand the principles:

```
CREATE TABLE Dummy(ID INT IDENTITY,SomeValue VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO Dummy(SomeValue) VALUES('Test1'),('Test2');
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyXMLFunction(@prm VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS XML
AS
BEGIN
RETURN
(
    SELECT @prm AS [@InsertedPrm]
          ,*
    FROM Dummy
    FOR XML PATH('Dummy'),ROOT('root')
);
END
GO

SELECT dbo.MyXMLFunction('1234');
GO

DROP FUNCTION dbo.MyXMLFunction;
DROP TABLE Dummy;
```

The Result

```
<root>
  <Dummy InsertedPrm="1234">
    <ID>1</ID>
    <SomeValue>Test1</SomeValue>
  </Dummy>
  <Dummy InsertedPrm="1234">
    <ID>2</ID>
    <SomeValue>Test2</SomeValue>
  </Dummy>
</root>
```